# Every time I tried to load gems for Jruby it gives me this error. This is after entering "gem install rails". Help please?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby

I am trying to download gems for jruby-1.7.0.RC2 but i get this error every time I try to push it through.

```
Error: Your application used more stack memory than the safety cap of 2048K.
```

Specify -J-Xss####k to increase it (#### = cap size in KB).
Specify -w for full StackOverflowError stack trace

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Can you post the output of `java -version` and you JRUBY_OPTS settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RVM to manage your Ruby runtimes, be sure to update it. See https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/331.

Answer (score 0):

That because Everytime you run

> gem install rails

it check for capsize JRUBY_OPTS just try changing that value

`export JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Xmx2048m`

change 2048 to a higher value (this basically Jruby heap space setting)

and then run `gem install rails`

Hope this help

btw 
Here the list of options you can use with http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/PerformanceTuning

Comment: -Xmx sets the heap size.  The error is complaining about stack memory.  Two different things.