# Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500M

Tags: logstash

I am getting the below error while running the logstash server :-

> Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500M.
>
> Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
>   Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace

Used the log-courier plugin for forwarding the logs to logstash server.But when we use multiline in log-courier we get the above error in logstash server.

Can somebody please help with this issue?

Comment: Is this what you need?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877961/every-time-i-tried-to-load-gems-for-jruby-it-gives-me-this-error-this-is-after

Answer (score 1):

increasing logstash LS_HEAP_SIZE value works for me.
on Redhat base systems (Centos,Redhat etc) 
go to /etc/sysconfig/logstash  and change LS_HEAP_SIZE

Comment: What should I do if I am using the windows version of logstash?